# Как написать AlertDialog со списком?

Tags: java, android

Способ есть [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/alertdialog.php), но информация очень старая (надо бы обойтись без deprecated методов).

Comment: Если без *deprecated*, то  делайте то же самое, что и в гайде по ссылке, но с помощью `DialogFragment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;  

 ...

alertdialog();
 ...


public void alertdialog() {
            final CharSequence[] items = {"один","два","три"};//имена методов Ваших в списке
            Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (item == 0) { //"один"
                        //method
                    }
                    if (item == 1) { //"два"
                        //method
                    }
                    if (item == 2) { //"три"
                        //method
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
```

Comment: Все работает, но в коде есть небольшие синтаксические ошибки. (пришлось подумать головой)

Comment: @ВладимирСалеев написали бы) помог:)

Comment: д я то разобрался. Заодно хотя бы немного подумал, а не просто скопировал и вставил.